# Why is 'nextTick' not behaving as expected here?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following program will hang in NodeJS, does anybody know why?

```
ended = false;

events = require('events');
eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
eventEmitter.on('end', function() {
  ended = true;
});
setTimeout(function() {
  eventEmitter.emit('end');
}, 100);

while (!ended) {
  process.nextTick();
}

console.log('ended');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`nextTick`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) isn't some kind of yield operation, it's for scheduling a callback to be called the next time the engine is free to do so. It's "hanging" because the `while` loop's exit condition is never satisfied (and can never be, with that code).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: because Node.JS is single-threaded.

Long answer: JavaScript is organized into a queue which holds events. These events when fired cannot be stopped until they finish the job. Also no other code can run parallelly, because Node.JS **is** single threaded. What this means is that this code:

```
while (!ended) {
  process.nextTick();
}
```

is an infinie loop. The `ended` variable will never change, because `end` handler cannot fire until the main event (i.e. the code you've shown us) finishes its job. And it never does.

Comment: JavaScript isn't single-threaded. Most JavaScript *implementations* implement it single-threaded, including all current browsers (barring the use of [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/)) and V8, the engine in Node (and Chrome). But there are multi-threaded implemenattions, including Rhino (as Rhino compiles JavaScript into JVM bytecode, and the JVM is multi-threaded).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Fair enough. I've changed it to "Node.JS".

Answer (score 1):

`process.nextTick();` does not call the next cycle of the main loop, the next cycle comes automatically, `.nextTick()` method is used to call a callback function on the next cycle, info: http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback.

`while(!ended)` is an infinite loop and that's why the application hangs, the `ended` variable will not change until the current cycle does not end, which is flooded by your while loop.